# R YaleToolkit change color of ptopts max and min and axis number format

Tags: r

I have a sparkline:

```
BusinessDate<-c("01-01-2014","01-02-2014","01-03-2014","01-04-2014","01-05-2014")
Corn<-c(1000000000,2,3,.0000000005,4)
Wheat<-c(2000000,1,8,10,.111111115)
risk<- data.frame(BusinessDate, Corn, Wheat)
sparklines(risk[,c("Corn", "Wheat")], 
       times=as.numeric(risk$BusinessDate),
       ptopts=('min.max'),  buffer= unit(1,'lines'),
       outer.margin=unit(c(4,12,4,15),'lines'))
```

I have a few questions about the plot that you will see when you run the above code:

(1) How can I change the y-axis from scientific notation to non-scientific notation?

(2) How can I change the color of the maximium to Green instead of red so that the minimum  is red but the maximum is green?

(3) How can I i change the data label of the ptopts to show in non-scientific notation. You will see the bottom plot has a data label that reads 2e +06. can I make it read  2000000 instead?

(4) Is it possible to color the points that are greater than 1 standard deviation of the time series. I image this would have to do with ptopts. But is it possible..if so how?

I know this is a lot of questions.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To get everything you ask for you will need to hack the code of `sparkline` ... not the same function as `sparklines` but rather a helper function. It has hard-coded format specs for the labels. I can get you the colors of the points:

```
sparklines(risk[,c("Corn", "Wheat")], 
       times=as.numeric(risk$BusinessDate),
       ptopts=list(labels='min.max', gp=gpar(col=c("red", "green") )),  buffer= unit(1,'lines'),
       outer.margin=unit(c(4,12,4,15),'lines'))
```

Look at the code of the two functions (by typing their names and see that the formatting is being conducted within the grid-graphics framework:

```
 libary(YaleToolkit)
 sparklines
 sparkline
```

I can get the labels to change but I have not figured out how to assign them properly in sequence to two different sets of points by supplying a `labels.ch` argument to the ptopts list.